# Scala Lift - MongoDB return specific fields from query

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I have the following:

```
User_Model.findAll(

    ("online" -> ("$gt" -> (

        (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - 60

    ))

)
```

What I'm trying to do is somehow define which fields for each record will be returned, rather than pulling the whole object.

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone is looking for a reference, this is how I ended up doing it:

```
User_Model.findAll(

    ("online" -> ("$gt" -> (

        (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - 60)

    )),

    ( /* Field names */

        ("uid" -> 1) ~ ("name" -> 1)

    ),

    Empty

)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Lift but according to [this](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/net/liftweb/mongodb/record/MongoMetaRecord.html) and [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) you should be able to do something like that:

```
User_Model.findAll(
    qry = ("online" -> ("$gt" -> ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - 60))), 
    keys = ("myfield" -> 1)
)
```